# Why connection to Ubuntu 20.04 on Hyper-V works via ssh, but not via other apps, in example vsftpd?

Tags: ubuntu, hyper-v

Trying to connect to my ubuntu 20.04 on Hyper-V. I can connect to openssh-server daemon, but not to vsftpd or other apps. When I tried to google it, found one question, where answered that I need to make external vSwitch.
Tried it, useless. Tried ufw disable, useless too.

Applying screenshot of
`sudo lsof -i -n -P`:

[image: screenshot]